# Use an excel cell to pass through to SQL code connected via ODBC

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I have an ODBC connection flowing into my Excel. I am trying to alter the Where clause by changing a cell in excel.

For example, I have the following code:

Odbc.Query("server=xxxx",
Select * from SALES
Where Asset = BrandA")

But I would like to alter 'BrandA' to whatever is in cell Sheet1!A1 instead of editing the query directly in PowerQuery. Is this possible?

Comment: IMHO it is like pulling tooth to do this using power query editor. If it doesn't need to be Power query then check: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-parameter-query-in-microsoft-query-c67d9af7-c8a0-4bf7-937c-087cb25f7ad3

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you need to make it a dynamic query. This article shows in detail how to do it:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).